# How to add button dynamically in UIActionSheet in iphone

Tags: iphone

i need to add button dynamically in UIActionSheet in iphone.Please help me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just alloc and init a new UIActionSheet instance and add the buttons one after another using `–addButtonWithTitle:`. This method returns you the index at which the button has been added to. You can then set the Index of the destructive button via -setDestructiveButtonIndex.

Here is an example that adds one button and adds another one if the boolean value `useDestructiveButton` is `YES` (and directly sets it as destructive button, making it red):

```
UIActionSheet *sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] init];
[sheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Button 1"];
if (useDestructiveButton) {
    [sheet setDestructiveButtonIndex:[sheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Button 2"]];
}
```

Don't forget to call the appropriate show method.

Answer (score 2):

```
UIActionSheet * as=[[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel",@"Cancel") destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
[as setTag:0];
[as addButtonWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"First Button",@"First Button")];
[as addButtonWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Second Button",@"Second Button")];
[as showInView:someController.view];
[as autorelease];
```

Also remember that your parent controller has to conform to the **UIActionSheetDelegate** protocol.